Problema arrancar con JWT con symfony 7.1
Primero de todo, gracias por la ayuda, soy nuevo en Symfony que se parece a Laravel como un huevo a una castaña.
Estoy desarrollando una API con JWT y no consigo que funcione el bundle LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.
Como ya había tocado bastantes cosas en el proyecto lo intente en una instalación limpia, pero me pasa lo mismo.
Para la instalación de Symfony:
# Recomendado para microservicio, app de consola o API:
symfony new my_project_directory --version="7.1.*"

Después de completar la instalación arranque el servidor:
symfony server:start -d

Abro la URL y puedo ver la página de inicio.
Detengo el servidor e instalo el bundle. Aquí la documentación.
El composer.json queda:
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/console": "7.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.1.*"
        }
    }
}

De los ficheros de documentación que indica la instalación tengo:
# config/routes.yaml

controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check

Probé a poner el bloque de "api_login_check" en primer lugar.
# config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    # enable_authenticator_manager: true # Only for Symfony 5.4

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~


    # ...
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # ...
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

y finalmente:
# config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 7200 # in seconds, default is 3600

Limpio cache:
php bin/console cache:clear

Compruebo rutas:
php bin/console debug:router

Salida:
----------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------- 
Name              Method   Scheme   Host   Path                      
----------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------- 
_preview_error    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}  
api_login_check   ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/login_check          
----------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------- 

Inicio el servidor:
symfony server:start -d

Hago la llamada de prueba que indica el servidor:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'

Y no funciona. Devuelve lo que parece una página HTML en la terminal, la última línea es:
<!-- Unable to find the controller for path &quot;/api/login_check&quot;. The route is wrongly configured. (404 Not Found) -->

He sacado este contenido de trazado:
    Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.
    Exception
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\
    NotFoundHttpException
    Show exception properties
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException {#221
    -statusCode: 404
    -headers: []
    }
    in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php (line 167)
            return $this->filterResponse($event->getResponse(), $request, $type);        }        // load controller        if (false === $controller = $this->resolver->getController($request)) {            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Unable to find the controller for path "%s". The route is wrongly configured.', $request->getPathInfo()));        }        $event = new ControllerEvent($this, $controller, $request, $type);        $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event, KernelEvents::CONTROLLER);        $controller = $event->getController();
    in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php -> handleRaw (line 76)
            $request->headers->set('X-Php-Ob-Level', (string) ob_get_level());        $this->requestStack->push($request);        $response = null;        try {            return $response = $this->handleRaw($request, $type);        } catch (\Throwable $e) {            if ($e instanceof \Error && !$this->handleAllThrowables) {                throw $e;            }
    in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php -> handle (line 182)
            $this->boot();        ++$this->requestStackSize;        $this->resetServices = true;        try {            return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);        } finally {            --$this->requestStackSize;        }    }
    in vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php -> handle (line 35)
    ) {    }    public function run(): int    {        $response = $this->kernel->handle($this->request);        if (Kernel::VERSION_ID >= 60400) {            $response->send(false);            if (\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request') && !$this->debug) {
    in vendor/autoload_runtime.php -> run (line 29)
    $app = $app(...$args);exit(    $runtime        ->getRunner($app)        ->run());
    require_once('/var/www/html/Symfony/api-jwt/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')
    in public/index.php (line 5)
    <?phpuse App\Kernel;require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';return function (array $context) {    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);};


He intentado activar logs poniendo en el .env `APP_DEBUG`` a true, este es mi .env:
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=779eddd461d6f49e4f98ca1abd1fe956
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=9380f30e08cabb9162f575619dace18771057e9bb874a6484127a855bf8cf3f1
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###

APP_DEBUG=true

En "var/logs/" no aparece nada.
Uso un entorno LAMP con PHP 8.3.

Editado

He probado a hacer llamadas GET y POST con una herramienta para probar APIs, con y sin el header Content-Type: application/json
